# Kraken EAPI: Invalid key

Tags: swift, cryptography

I am trying to do a client with swift however I cannot communicate with the private api {"error": ["EAPI: Invalid key"]}

I use CCHmac function and tried to have a look at different api implementation.
I just can't get whats wrong... 
Here is my code:

```
 func getTradeBalance(basedAsset: String, completionBlock: @escaping BlockResult) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "\(krakenUtils.rootUrl)/\(krakenUtils.version)/private/Balance") else {
        return
    }
    let nonce: String = String(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970.rounded()))

    let path = "/\(krakenUtils.version)/private/Balance"
    let pubKey = krakenUtils.publicKey

    let params = ["nonce": nonce]

    //Sign = HMAC-SHA512 of URI + SHA256-POSTDATAS + base64decodedSecret


    let sign = getMessageSignature(path: path,
        nonce: nonce)

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post,
                      parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                      headers: ["API-Key": pubKey,
                                "API-Sign": sign])
        .responseJSON { resp in
            let result = self.handleResponse(result: resp)
            guard let json = result.0 else {
                completionBlock(nil, result.1)
                return
            }
            print(json)
    }

}

private func getMessageSignature(path: String, nonce: String) -> String {
    let secretDecoded = Data(base64Encoded: krakenUtils.privateKey, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))!
    let np = (nonce + "nonce=" + nonce).sha256().data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
    var pathNP = path.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
    pathNP.append(contentsOf: np)

    let lRet = HMAC.sign(data: pathNP, algorithm: .sha512, key: secretDecoded).base64EncodedString()
    return lRet
}

 public static func sign(data: Data, algorithm: Algorithm, key: Data) -> Data {
    let signature = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.allocate(capacity: algorithm.digestLength)

    data.withUnsafeBytes { dataBytes in
        key.withUnsafeBytes { keyBytes in
            CCHmac(algorithm.algorithm, keyBytes, key.count, dataBytes, data.count, signature)
        }
    }

    return Data(bytes: signature, count: algorithm.digestLength)
}
```

This is guide for authenticated call HTTPS Header:

```
API-Key = API key
API-Sign = Message signature using HMAC-SHA512 of (URI path + SHA256(nonce + POST data)) and base64 decoded secret API key
```

This is guide for authenticated call POST Data:

```
nonce = always increasing unsigned 64 bit integer
otp = two-factor password (if two-factor enabled, otherwise not required)
```

Comment: were you able to figure this out ? I am at exact situation and all I get is `invalid key` response. I even tried playing with the encoding but result stays the same

Answer (score 4):

For the API-Key you use krakenUtils.publicKey. The name suggests you use some public key (do not know where you got it)
However this should be your personal API-Key. You can get it at the kraken site (login with your account) and create an API key. You also get your API-code here. They go together as a pair

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, many users (including myself) who have attempted to use Kraken’s API have encountered and reported similar problems (INVALID KEY).   Recently I reported the issue I was having to a Kraken rep…after an exchange with several reps it was discovered that there was a flaw in the posted Kraken example on their website.  Here is some of the exchange:

...”In the method QueryPrivateEndpoint there is a line of code (should be line 256 from the file downloaded) that looks like this:

```
String apiEndpointFullURL = baseDomain + privatePath + endPointName + "?" + inputParameters;
```

It needs to be modified to look like this:

```
String apiEndpointFullURL = baseDomain + privatePath + endPointName;
```

After you make that code change, the Invalid Key error should go away.
…….
Thank you for your gratitude and pointing out the mistake to our attention.
We are pleased to know the issue has been resolved.
“……

They will post the update to their example code on their website.
Also, it’s worth noting that an improper/inconsistent ORDER of the parameters in a call that has parameters associated with it can cause an INVALID KEY error.